# How can i concat 2 pandas dataframe with column filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframe

**DF1**

| rowid | city | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | citya | 10 | 8 |
| 2 | cityb | 20 | 9 |

**DF2**

| city | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cityc | 10 | 8 |
| cityd | 10 | 4 |
| citye | 10 | 1 |
| citye | 20 | 9 |
| cityf | 20 | 4 |
| citye | 20 | 1 |

I want to concat 2 dataframe from id2 values.
But i need to add DF2 under to DF1 rows without duplicated values like this,

Note: on df1 i have too many id2 values with diffrent row number like (id2 : 10 , id3: 2) and i need to filter by row values before insert df2 values under to df1 rows

| rowid | city | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | citya | 10 | 8 |
|  | cityd | 10 | 4 |
|  | citye | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | cityb | 20 | 9 |
|  | cityf | 20 | 4 |
|  | cityg | 20 | 1 |

I dont have any idea about that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
>>> (pd.concat([df1, df2.assign(rowid='')])
       .drop_duplicates(['id2', 'id3'])
       .sort_values('id2', ignore_index=True))

  rowid   city  id2  id3
0     1  citya   10    8
1        cityd   10    4
2        citye   10    1
3     2  cityb   20    9
```

Comment: thanks but i need to add df2 id2 values under to first row of df1. thats will repeat for all id2 values

Comment: on df1 i have too many id2 values with diffrent row number like 
id2 : 10 , id3: 2 

i need to filter by row values before insert df2 values

Comment: Explain me how you can sort the dataframe if in `df2` there is no rowid column?

Comment: yes i dont have row id i just have id2 and id3 values